# Checking the value of output signal over a period of time

Tags: verilog, test-bench

I've got an `initial` block which calls a task named `power_task` as below

```
initial begin
#10;
power_task;
end
```

Inside the power task, I've two signals `power_a` and `power_b`. Initially, `power_a` goes low and after a certain skew, `power_b` goes low. As long as both the signals are low, I need to check the output `q`. Output `q` should be low during the time window where `power_a` and `power_b` signals are low. Since there are no other signals like a clock, I'm not sure how to continuously monitor `q`.  I've written something like below

```
task power_task;

#1;
power_a=0;
#5; //skew
power_b=0;
   if (power_a==0 && power_b==0 && q==0) begin
   $display("pass");
   end
#50;
power_b=1;
#5;
power_a=1;
end
endtask
```

In the above task, the `if` statements check the value of `q` only after both signals are low and not during the entire 50 ns time window. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `wait` statement in a `fork` block

```
task power_task;
  begin
    reg fail;
    fail = 0;
    #1 power_a=0;
    #5 power_b=0; //skew
    fork : check_q
      wait (q) fail = 1;
      #50 begin
          if (fail) 
            $display("fail");
          else
            $display("pass");
          disable check_q;
        end
    join
    power_b=1;
    #5 power_a=1;
  end
endtask
```

Not exactly sure why you need to check that `power_a/b` are still 0 unless there is some other code that could change it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `always` block outside of the task, a control signal (`check_en`) and a flag variable (`pass`):

```
reg pass = 1;
reg check_en = 0;

always @(check_en, q) begin
    if (check_en && q) begin
        $display("fail");
        pass = 0;
    end
end

initial begin
    #10;
    power_task();
    if (pass) $display("pass");
end

task power_task;
    #1;
    power_a=0;
    #5; //skew
    power_b=0;
    check_en = 1;
    #50;
    check_en = 0;
    power_b=1;
    #5;
    power_a=1;
endtask
```

The `always` block will continuously monitor the `q` signal for any changes when enabled.